# Travis-CI Java build project with own dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, travis-ci

I've read through the help on travis as well as searching here. (Can be my phasing of the question)
I can't seem to find the right question to ask for the following scenario (which must have been asked before - plenty of time).

I have 3 Maven Java projects on GitHub (and they are all synced with Travis); `LibA`, `LibB` and `ProjectC`.

`ProjectC` has 2 dependencies, `LibA` and `LibB`.  `LibA` and `LibB` builds fine in Travis because their dependencies are available publicly.

How do I update .travis.yml file to tell the travis compiler to build those libraries first, store it and then build `ProjectC` (using the just build libraries)

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like those libs should be build within a single multi module build instead of distributed repos and builds...Will those libs released at the same time? Having the same version number?

Comment: One of the libs is tightly tied to the project but the other one is my general functionalities.

Comment: could you post the solution? i am very interested in this topic